# Missing Python.h in Windows

Tags: python, c

I'm trying to run some python code from my c program by using the python.h header but I keep getting
`fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory`

After checking my anaconda environment, I have found a Python.h file in `...Anaconda/envs/myenv/include`
I tried adding this path to my system variable's PATH but it didn't work. How can I include the Python.h file from my anaconda env to my program?

Comment: If it's a C program, please don't spam the C++ tag.

Comment: What are you using to compile your program?
Don't add it to your system PATH but to your compilation include flags

Comment: `PATH` is only used for executables, not C headers. Tell your compiler or build system to add this path. On gcc and clang, for example, it's the `-I` flag.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Thomas It worked! i just used the -I flag followed by path to search for my header file.

Comment: Well I guess I should post an answer then :) Next time, please include the necessary details about your platform, build system and compilation commands, so we don't have to guess what the solution might be for your particular case.

Comment: @Thomas My apologies for the leaving out details. Will make sure to include as much as possible with future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` is only used for executables, not C headers. Tell your compiler or build system to add this path. On gcc and clang, for example, it's the `-I` flag.